# Lua Socket Lib Question

Tags: sockets, lua

I am writing an app taking advantage of Lua Socket lib. Here is a simple code snippet that describes my problem.

```
local com=require("socket");
local socket=com.tcp();
local hello="hi stack overflow";
local myIP="192.168.1.1";
local myPort = 2000;
local err = nil;

-- Main
while 1
if(~err) then
err = socket:send(hello);
else
  if(socket:connect("myIP", myPort))) then
  err = 1;
  end -- second if
end -- first if
waitfor(10); -- wait for 10 sec.
do
```

(I actually didn't run this particular code but it is identical to the running code in my problem).
When I see that if socket is closed, this code cannot reopen it. I would have guessed once we grab the master TCP object we can open and close as we please.

I can force this code to work by repeating the socket.tcp() call however I suspect that leaves the previous object somewhere in memory and I want to avoid this.

Comment: This code isn't syntactically correct. And reusing a variable for a new object as socket=com.tcp() does, will result in the original object being collected in the next garbage collection cycle. Which is OK as long as you don't overtax it.

Comment: @jpjacobs could you please elaborate? I am not reusing any variable.. I first get a handle for socket lib via com and I create a tcp object called socket. Later I refer to socket for all communication. (The code may not compile, my own code was far more complex than this so I didn't post it). If you are saying this will not compile, you are right, but if you are saying I shouldn't be using the local variable com and socket this way, I guess, I need to better understand lua. thx.

Answer (score 3):

Well, things that are wrong in your code (starting from the top)

- It's a bad habbit reusing default module names like socket, it'll confuse people reading your code
- While loop syntax is `while <condition> do <statements> end`
- setting err to nil is useless in this case, as it does not exist in the snippet scope
- it makes no sense to send to an unconnected master.
- negation is done with `not` instead of `~`
- you pass the string "myIP" instead of the actual IP

then there's also a function `socket.sleep()` you might be interested in.

I'm wondering why you complicate the loop this way, and don't just use something like:

```
require("socket");
local soc=socket.tcp();
local hello="hi stack overflow";
local myIP="192.168.1.1";
local myPort = 2000;



local stat,err=socket:connect(myIP, myPort)
if not stat then
   error(err)
else
    -- Main
    while not err do
        err = socket:send(hello)
        socket.sleep(10)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this code.. the issue is the following, assume I lost the connection.. (the remote port went offline for a sec  and came back).. When I try to send something I get a message saying closed.. Now, I want to re-open and I just call soc:connect(myIP, myport) [i think your code should say soc:connect as opposed to socket:connect].. But this soc:connect call fails. If I call soc=socket.tcp() one more time and call soc:connect after that things are ok.. This doesn't make sense to me.. (This is what I was trying to ask, I will never post a code that doesn't work from now on)

Comment: Assuming you don't get error's to much there is absolutly nothing against doing creating a new connection. It's logical that it works after using `soc=socket.tcp()` again because you create a _new_ connection. AFAIK there's no way to reopen a closed socket. And from point of view of garbage, the collector will take care.

Comment: +1 for the great points jpjacobs.  @Frank, you should post some corrected code with the `close` as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure that `~` is a valid NOT operator. Last time I checked, anyway.

Comment: @DeadMG: no it is not (in both senses ;)). try `= ~false` in an interpreter. You're probably confusing with the inequality `~=`.

Answer (score 0):

The connect call will never work as you are passing the string "myIP" not the variable `myIP` which contains your target Ip address.

Comment: good point.. But moot, discussion is why I have to recall soc=socket.tcp()? the object should have been there already..